# What is the maximum number of flags that make sense in an enum?

Tags: c#

Considering this type of enum, in which you can use bitwise comparisons to basically combine multiple booleans into a single data field:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options 
{
    None    = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    Option4 = 8
}
```

I have read through the MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 and done some Google searching, but I still have some architecture questions.

It seems that with up to [EDIT: eight] options (plus "none"), you can fit any combination of flags into a single byte of storage.  Is this actually how it is handled at runtime, or is it just stuck into an Int32 with the remainder of the space wasted?  Is there an efficiency disadvantage to adding a ninth option, and if so, how many more options can you add before hitting the next efficiency disadvantage?  Is there a rule of thumb about how large one of these should be?  I am considering using this for an application where at least 6 flags would be needed, but it could conceivably grow to include 8-12 flags (but I am interested in the theoretical limits as well.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one extra is too much, one less is too little

Comment: "It seems that with up to four options (plus "none"), you can fit any combination of flags into a single byte of storage." - why?

Comment: don't use `0` value in flag enum. it can lead to strange problems when working with that enum. `None` shouldn't be member of that enum

Comment: Overly worrying about data packing is a bit like file allocation. In the early 1990s, some people used to worry about how a text file with 20 characters in it would still take up an entire MS-DOS 512 byte cluster on our whopping 40 MB hard drives and complain about lost space.  They would end up resorting to compressing everything which just created another problem - that of compute whenever your needed to view that file.  Now if the hard drive consisted of nothing but small text files sure, but by the same token, .NET programs are rarely just `Flags enum`s.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment of M.kazem Akhgary; it is 100% contrary to design guidelines. Instead, read the actual design guidelines at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You have at minimum a two billion byte address space per process and disk space is running at a few dollars per trillion bytes, and you are worrying about one byte vs four.  Worry about something more important.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Actually, [StyleCop rule CA1008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx) thinks it is fine to have a zero-valued flags member, as long as it is called `None`. And the [best practices list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058(v=vs.110).aspx) basically says the same.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Defining `None` as 0 is very common in .NET. Obviously, `None` should not be used with other flags or bitwise operations. It should generally be obvious from the context what do make sense or not. The only case where I would not defined None for a flag would be if it is required to have at least one flag set.

Comment: In this instance, I am not so worried about space efficiency, but I am looking for a convenient way to store booleans in a database when their importance is contextual - ie: if it is a customer, I would need 6 bit fields that would always be null for vendors, and if it is a vendor, I would need a few bit fields that would always be null for customers...  Why add 10 columns, when I can just store an int?  I guess the data type doesn't matter so much, I was just seeking a greater understanding before I start cowboy coding.

Comment: Why not just use a bit for boolean?

Comment: @EricLippert Regarding the MS Link, I don't quite understand what they're getting at.  If I want to test the second bit for non-zero I would `if ((0x01010 & 0x00010) != 0) { // bit is set}`  but following their suggestion of defining a `enum Foo { None = 0 ....}` then following their logic, I could accidentally do `if ((0x01010 & MyFlags.None) != 0) { // the 'none flag is set}`.   It goes against my Z80; 6809E; and 68000 assembly language experience.  I'd rather not put `None` into the `enum`.  Want to test for zero in hardware, test for zero, don't do a bit test

Comment: @Paparazzi - typically I do, but I also have a lot of tables with a dozen or more bit fields that mostly hold null values.  Think of these as the extra data associated with inherited classes... I don't want to create a bunch of duplicate tables for closely-related entities, but if I add a ton of extra columns that don't apply to most of the rows, it creates some avoidable complications with ORM mapping, etc.  I'm just trying to think outside the box.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for the link. so when writing enumeration algorithms i.e iterating over all enum members i should be careful that `None` doesn't mess with my results. i think if you have `0` that already means all flags are cleared. so no need for such member. but i see your point. there may be some use cases.

Comment: @MickyD It is not exactly what I said... **You can use `None` in an enum flag**. `if (options & (Options.Options1 | Options.Option2)) == Options.None)...` is perfectly fine for example. What is wrong is something like `options & Options.None` or something like `options &= ~Options.None;` Since by convention `None` mean 0, every competent person should understand code and not be affected by subtilities... **It would become problematic if name would not always be `None`.**

Comment: @MickyD: You would not do the bit arithmetic at all if testing a flag in a flags enum. You would call `HasFlag` rather than twiddling bits like a C programmer.

Comment: You shouldn't use flags in the Database. They don't save space since SQL Server stores up to eight bit columns in a single byte. And what's worse - they can't benefit from an index.

Comment: @Phil1970 Well you did say _"Obviously, None should not be used with other flags or bitwise operations"_.  Anyway I'm over arguing with people

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric. Was not aware .NET 4 introduced `HasFlags`.  Still, my point remains and the MS suggestion is just plain silly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default any enum is backed by a `int`, which means it has 32 bits in it. That could hold up to 32 distinct flags as each flag is just setting a bit in the `int`.

When you have less than 32 flags it still takes up the space of a single `int` which is 4 bytes. You are allowed to choose other types to be the underlying type from the list `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

So if you only had 4 options you could declare your enum as

```
[Flags]
public enum Options : byte
{
    None    = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    Option4 = 8
}
```

and then it would only take up one byte of memory, you would be able to add up to 8 options before you ran out of bits to use.

As for design best practices, just read [the best practices page from Microsoft on Enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I did read the best practices page - that's the link I referenced - but it doesn't even go so far as to show the syntax much less any deeper considerations.  This makes sense, though.

Comment: @ElementalPete for syntax and deeper considerations see the page for [the `enum` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), that is where i got the list of underlying types you are allowed to use.

Comment: the compiler does not warn or error if there are more values on the enum type than bits in the underlying type. the values just wrap around and repeat. this leads to curious effects and bugs that are hard to find, when two or more differently named enum values have the same numeric value and suddenly match `HasFlag` and `==` operations.

Comment: Why is there no compiler error when I inherit from int, but have more than 32 members? Does compiler automatically take Int64?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the underlying type of any enum you want.
If you don't, it will always be `Int32`.

Also, `byte` can hold up to 8 flags.

Comment: 8 flags for a byte (9 including None).

Comment: @Phil1970: Oops; fixed.

Comment: @MickyD - Scott Chamberlain's answer is basically the same as this with the extra info that you are requesting.  I appreciate both answers - either one basically told me what I needed to know!

Comment: @ElementalPete Ah true, I missed that.  :)

Comment: If I use more than 32 members and still inherit from int, does compiler use Int64 for me? Because there is no compile time error.